# When use proguard,Warning: can't find referenced method 'void deleteAll()' in class javax.microedition.lcdui.List

Tags: java-me, proguard

Everyone:
I developed one project,which run in j2me platform.When i use proguard,it warning me the below thing,anyone can help?

```
Initializing...
Warning: BtPrinterScreen: can't find referenced method 'void deleteAll()' in class javax.microedition.lcdui.List
Warning: BuyScreenNo: can't find referenced method 'void setTitle(java.lang.String)' in class javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable
Warning: BuyScreenNo2: can't find referenced method 'void setTitle(java.lang.String)' in class javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable
Warning: BuyScreenNo3: can't find referenced method 'void setTitle(java.lang.String)' in class javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable
Warning: DecodeCanvas: can't find referenced method 'int getWidth()' in class javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable
Warning: DecodeCanvas: can't find referenced method 'int getHeight()' in class javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable
Warning: MenuScreen: can't find referenced method 'void deleteAll()' in class javax.microedition.lcdui.List
Warning: MenuScreen: can't find referenced method 'boolean platformRequest(java.lang.String)' in class javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet
Warning: ResultScreen: can't find referenced method 'void setFont(javax.microedition.lcdui.Font)' in class javax.microedition.lcdui.StringItem
Warning: ResultScreen2: can't find referenced method 'void setFont(javax.microedition.lcdui.Font)' in class javax.microedition.lcdui.StringItem
Warning: there were 10 unresolved references to program class members.
```

Waiting your help,always online.

Answer (score 0):

`deleteAll` method was added at MIDP 2.0. Be sure to use this version or later.

Comment: Thanks you read my question,but I want to tell you I already sloved this problem.Share for everyone.
I add jar package one by one,and test,so I found can't add same package at the sametime.Like the below file:
cldcapi10.jar
cldcapi11.jar
Just add one is fine.And also like
midpapi10.jar
midpapi20.jar
midpapi21.jar
Just add the last one is ok,my question is this reason,when I just add the last one,and test is ok,so happy me.

This one just suitable this question,but the others you can try this method,but maybe can work,good luck for you.